# Statistics Probability Algebra Issue

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, statistics, statistical-inference

Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be two independent random variables so that the variances of $X_1$ and $X_2$ are $x_1 = k$ and $x_2 = 2$, respectively. Given that the variance of $Y = 3X_2 - X_1$ is $25$, find $k$.

I have tried a lot but now finding the correct answer I think. I have got the answer as $19$ which is wrong.

Can anybody explain the process which I should follow to answer this Question?

Help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the variance of $3X_2$?

Comment: The flaw in your calculation is that while $X_1,X_2$ are independent, $X_1$ and $X_1$ are not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following comes directly from the definition that $Var(aX+bY)=a^2Var(X)+b^2Var(Y)$

$$\begin{align*}
Var(Y)
&=Var(3X_2-X_1)\\\\
&=(3)^2Var(X_2)+(-1)^2Var(X_1)\\\\
&=9Var(X_2)+Var(X_1)\\\\
&=18+k
\end{align*}$$

So $k$ must be $7$.

Comment: Thanks for this

Comment: @HimanshuChawla Welcome to MathSE...if this answer helped you, please mark it as accepted (the check mark below the voting buttons). Also consider upvoting it.